# Can we store Spark-SQL-Kafka offset in MySQL table instead of HDFS or S3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a simple Spark-SQL-Kafka program which reads from Kafka, and writes to HDFS.

For check-pointing I have used HDFS and S3 in past, it works fine.

Is there a way where I can use MySQL for check-pointing ?

```
.option("checkpointLocation", ConfigLoader.getValue("checkpointPath"))
```

How can we configure to MySQL table?

```java
DataStreamReader kafkaDataStreamReader = sparkSession.readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", ConfigLoader.getValue("brokers"))
        .option("group.id", ConfigLoader.getValue("groupId"))
        .option("subscribe", ConfigLoader.getValue("topics"))
        .option("failOnDataLoss", false);
Dataset<Row> rawDataSet = kafkaDataStreamReader.load();                         
rawDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("rawEventView");

sqlCtx.sql("select * from rawEventView")
        .writeStream()
        .partitionBy(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList(("date_year,date_month,date_day,date_hour,date_minute").split(","))))
        .format("csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("compression","gzip")
        .option("delimiter", "~")
        .option("checkpointLocation", ConfigLoader.getValue("checkpointPath"))
        .option("path", ConfigLoader.getValue("recordsPath"))
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
        .trigger(ProcessingTime.create(Integer.parseInt(ConfigLoader.getValue("kafkaProcessingTimeInSeconds")), TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .start()
        .awaitTermination();
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: In this case I want to track that the my app is continuously reading from kafka, I understand I can do the same by monitoring and reading offset files from HDFS and S3, but I want to know if I can store the offset in MySQL and generate report ..

Comment: @Manjesh: I have not implemented in MySQL. But we store the offset detail in HBase.

Comment: @DasarathyDR , does Spark-Structured-Streaming provides any interface that I  need to extended ? Is there is any blog/link that explains the approach ?